# karaf features vs deploy folder

Tags: apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix, bundles

What are the advantages of using features descriptor compared to using deploy folder for deploying bundles in karaf.

Based on this answer it seems for Production usages, it is better to depend on the features rather than using deploy folder. Are there any specific advantages of using the features over deploy folder.

[Startup for bundles placed in the deploy folder of Karaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160318/startup-for-bundles-placed-in-the-deploy-folder-of-karaf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Karaf team always states, the deploy folder should not be used for production.

Due to the way bundles are deployed, a feature is much better in usage, especially if bundles define dependencies on other features, configurations etc. see the documentation at karaf.apache.org.

Comment: The team does not state the interesting part: why?